# Powershell Scripting -- Docx to PDF

Tags: powershell

I have a script (below) that converts docx to PDF.  However, after it gets to file 204 or 205, I get a memory exceeded message and the process stops.  I have about 40,000 docx that need to be converted.  Can someone help with making this more efficient or possibly add a loop that closes the application after every 150 documents then re-opens the application and continues?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
$documents_path = 'C:\Users\jgentile\Desktop\Purdue\DocX\All'

$word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

$i=0
Get-ChildItem -Path $documents_path -Filter *.doc? | ForEach-Object {

If( $i%150 ) { $word_app.Quit(); $word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application }

$document = $word_app.Documents.Open($_.FullName)
$pdf_filename = "C:\Users\jgentile\Desktop\Purdue\PDFs\$($_.BaseName)_Discipline.pdf"
$document.SaveAs([ref] $pdf_filename, [ref] 17)
$document.Close()
$i++

}
$word_app.Quit()
```

Comment: Could you explain the reason to why you haven't added the loop you are requesting yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong version.  The problem with this loop is that is continues to open up a new Word Process for every file.  So the generation gets slower and slower until eventually I run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

An if-test needs a `true` or `false` value. `1%150` will return `1`, `2%150` will return `2` etc. -> value is not null. You're if-test will always be true, except for 0 which is converted to false. So your script actually works the opposite way of how you want it.

You should test if `$i%150 -eq 0`. That will only happend when `$i` is 0, 150, 300, 450 etc. If you don't want it to run on 0, start your `$i` on 1. :)

Try

```
If($i%150 -eq 0) { $word_app.Quit(); $word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application }
```

You could also just flip the if-test(turning false to true) using `if(-not($i%150))`, but I think `-eq 0` is more readable.

**UPDATE**: As @Cole9350 pointed out, you should also release the Comobject after calling `Quit()` to free up the handle on the resource(process) so that Word closes properly. Like:

```
If($i%150 -eq 0) {
    $word_app.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word_app)
    $word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
}
```

Comment: Okey, my bad. 0 is converted to bool `false`, but the solution still works, so no need to downvote. My code will run just like yours: the `true`-script will be executed on 0,150,300,450 etc. And personally, `($i%150 -eq 0)` is alot easier to read than `(!($i%150))` because is pure math.

Comment: Sorry, it was because it didn't really solve the problem. If you never release the comobject then you will eventually run out of memory. The link in my post explains why

Comment: I'm aware the releasecomobject is required to free up the process, but that wasn't the biggest issue in his script. :)

Comment: The problem stated in the question was "I get a memory exceeded message and the process stops". The issue was with memory management, not processing speed.

Comment: You are ofc. right, I've never said otherwise. I'm just saying that fixing it so he only creates 25 com-objects instead of 3975 fixes 99% of the problem. Releasing the comobject in a proper way is important, but that's pretty much polishing compared to the other problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The way your if statement is set up, it would execute every iteration of the loop except for 150, which I'm guessing is not what you intended. Also, you should release the comobject in order to avoid out of memory exception

```
If(!($i%150)) { 
    $word_app.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word_app)
    Remove-Variable word_app
    $word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application 
}
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx

Comment: You're correct abot the `releasecomobject`-method which he should use, but the biggest problem with his code was that he was making 4000 comobject. :P  Also, it would be a lot better to simply make `150` a parameter in the script if you want to make it dynamic. Creating a new com object for each file could become a big performance hit.

Comment: @FrodeF. Yes, a param would be a better solution to avoid performance issues.